# An indicator that shows how much do I perform relatively to other users

Tags: feature-request, reputation-leagues

I'm new to community as a contributor. Right now I'm answering questions for almost 5 days and getting a general feel that I am pretty useful.

When I'm watching my user page, I can see lot of numbers and for more serious users I do see an 'overall rank'... Is there a chance to observer such a ratio more specifically? such as ratio per tag or per badge?

After all, these numbers are just numbers... I think it is hard to tell what's my **real stats** relying on just numbers and an overall score.

Comment: There is a [top users page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/topusers) for every tag (warning: numbers there can be depressing). Not so much for badges, but you can see how many badges of a particular type have been earned so far.

Comment: this is just great! i assumed that if such a thing does exists it will have a direct link from my user page...

Comment: Welcome! I scanned some of your answers; here is a tip. Please use proper capitalization! See also the edit @gnat did to this very post.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi The "30 Days" numbers aren't too depressing, other than the ridiculous difference between me and Jon Skeet. The "Overall" list is *very* depressing though :)

Comment: there is also a SEDE query to show how close you are to bronze|silver|gold tag badges

Comment: @Plutonix You can also just look at your tag scores on your profile page... (updated daily)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to to the main site -> Users -> weekly / monthly / quarterly reputation leagues (At the bottom of the page)

Choose at the top which scale you want. (Week/Month/Quater/Year/All Time)
If you want to know what is your position choose "X Rank". (X = scale you selected.) if you want to know how you changed choose "Rank Change". I believe "Total Reputation" is irrelevant.

You need to be signed up to SE too to perform this first.

### Edit

As for @yackovmandeszaig's request I've added [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8Uhz.png) and [direct link](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow).

Comment: any chance to a screen shot? it sounds good but i'm pretty lost here

Comment: @yackovmandeszaig Updated.